# How to organise my project in Code Igniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to Code Igniter. I am going to build simple project where following modules will be existed:

1. News
2. Event
3. Gallery

Now, how do I organise my project in modular format in Code Igniter.

In simple , we can create controller of each modules in : 
`application/controllers/`
and display part in `application/views/`,
but I want to keep in modular base.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home)

Or just add a extra folders to your controllers folder

application/controllers/news

application/views/news

Just make sure you point your views to them

```
$this->load->view('news/some_file');
```

**For HMVC you could do something like:**

```
application/modules/news
|->controllers
  |---- news.php
  |---- admin
        |--- news.php
        |--- ajax.php
|->views
  |---- partials
  |---- some_view.php
  |---- admin
        |--- admin_views.php
```

Comment: Thanks Philip for the suggestion. But I was expecting modules to be created inside application/modules/news
Is there any way to create modules as in Yii framework, you can see separate Controller, Module, View and Modules.

Comment: updated answer but I guess it was not what you were after after seeing your updated comment.  Im not familiar with Yii Framework but I guess you want each module to contain its own config files, widgets etc?

Comment: :) awesome.Thanks once again Philips.

Comment: welcome.  I recommend you read the routing documentation otherwise you might end up with messy urls.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information at user guide and search for some code examples. After understanding flow you can figure out how to make modular system

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/appflow.html